# Como encontrar puntos (A,B,C) y distancias (dist 1, dist 2, dist 3) validas para generar un sistema de ecuaciones de 3x3 que tenga solucion

Tags: javascript, python, busqueda, calculo, posicionamiento

Necesito resolver un problema donde debo encontrar la posicion de 1 observador (x,y), a partir de 3 coordenadas dadas y 3 distancias dadas.

MI PREGUNTA es como puedo encontrar puntos (A,B, C) y distancias (distancia 1, distancia 2, distancia 3) validas para generar un sistema de ecuaciones de 3x3 que tenga solucion. Al final detallo un poco más la consulta por si no se entiende ahora.

DATOS ENTREGADOS:

- Se entregan 3 posiciones de satelites y 3 distancias de cada satelite al observador.

Las 3 posiciones de cada uno de los satelites son:

```
Punto A(3,4)
Punto B(1,2)
Punto C(5,1)
```

Las 3 distancias desde cada PUNTO al OBSERVADOR.

```
distancia 1 = Distancia del Punto A(3,4),  la distancia = 1
distancia 2 = Distancia del Punto B(1,2),  la distancia = 2
distancia 3 = Distancia del Punto C(5,1),  la distancia = 3
```

SOLUCION:
Para resolver esto, utilizó la siguiente ecuación:

```
distancia = sqrt (   (x2 - x1)^2    +   (y2 - y1)^2  )  )
```

La solución de esto es generar 3 ecuaciones cuadráticas de 2 variables:

```
ECUACION 1: Tomo el punto del OBSERVADOR como x2, y2 y el punto A(x1=3,y1=4)
  
1 = sqrt (   (x2 - 3)^2    +   (y2 - 4)^2  )  )


ECUACION 2: Tomo el punto del OBSERVADOR como x2, y2 y el punto B(x1=1,y1=2)
  
2 = sqrt (   (x2 - 1)^2    +   (y2 - 2)^2  )  )


ECUACION 3: Tomo el punto del OBSERVADOR como x2, y2 y el punto C(x1=5,y1=1)

3 = sqrt (   (x2 - 5)^2    +   (y2 - 1)^2  )  )
```

Con esto tengo un sistema de ecuaciones de 3x3, se como resolver un sistema de ecuaciones de 3x3, pero como es cuadrática al evaluar algunos puntos que me he dado no tengo solución.

PREGUNTA:

```
Mi consulta es como puedo generar los puntos (A, B, C) y las distancias (distancia 1, distancia 2, distancia 3) para poder resolver el sistema de ecuaciones de 3x3 que me de solucion al problema y que me permita encontrar ls posicion (x,y) del OBSERVADOR, de manera que sea valido para la posicion del OBSERVADOR. Ya que me he dado puntos al azar y no he encontrado solucion.
```

Si saben de alguna pagina donde poder generar estos puntos para tener resultados validos.

Comment: No parece una pregunta válida con la temática de [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Acá te dejo un link donde podes ingresar tus ecuaciones y te las grafica, ahí tenes un ejercicio resuelto y es interactivo, sobre la izquierda en el panel inferior podes editar los valores y vas a obtener tu solución
El enunciado del ejercicio es este:
Dado el siguiente sistema de ecuaciones:

```
2x + 3y - z = 7 
x + 4y + 2z = 2 
x + y + z = 4"
```

https://www.geogebra.org/m/cezQC2Sq ;)